# Is there a way to get results based on the results of a sub query?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to generate a list of projects that members of my website are connected to via tasks they are assigned to. So for example my MySQL query looks like:

```
$result = $con->query("SELECT ProjectID, ProjectName, StartDate, EndDate, Bio, AStartDate, AEndDate, POwnerID
                            FROM projects 
                            WHERE ProjectID = (SELECT ProjectID
                                              FROM tasks
                                              INNER JOIN usertasks ON tasks.TaskID = usertasks.TaskID
                                              WHERE UserID = '$User')
                            ORDER BY StartDate");
```

So the nested query is returning the two expected values `(9,10)`, but the main query returns `boolean false`.

Is it possible to use MySQL query to gain the results I am looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when your nested query return more than 1 value you must use in

```
WHERE ProjectID IN (SELECT ProjectID
```

to be:

```
$result = $con->query("SELECT ProjectID, ProjectName, StartDate, EndDate, Bio,
AStartDate, AEndDate, POwnerID FROM projects  WHERE ProjectID 
IN (SELECT ProjectID FROM tasks INNER JOIN usertasks ON 
tasks.TaskID = usertasks.TaskID  WHERE UserID = '$User')
ORDER BY StartDate");
```